# Retrieving a specific cell in a google fusion table using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, google-fusion-tables

How do I retrieve a specific cell in a google fusion table?

In my fusion table I have this column that contains dates.  How can I retrieve those dates and display them on my webpage?

I have read various documents but they talk about how to retrieve the whole data in the fusion table thus displaying all the data in my webpage which in my case I only need to retrieve dates so that I can manipulate on how am I going to display other data using the date.

Answer (score 0):

See the [SQL reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select). In particular, note the part of the select where you can specify which columns to retrieve, like this: select column1, column2 from mytableid